# Firebase Android, how can I sign out a user by email?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have to check if a user is already logged in and if it is to sign it out. My app is set to log in with email and pass. I want to force the sign out by using the email. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase auth is provide signout method.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Event Signout

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                // code here
            }
        });
    }
}
```